# Getting data from multiple tables in my SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    sa.MSISDN, 
    MIN(sa.DateRegistered) AS firstReg, 
    s.DateRegistered AS currentReg,  
    MAX(sa.DateRegistered) AS previousReg 
FROM 
    sms.dbo.SubscriptionsArchive sa 
INNER JOIN 
    sms.dbo.Subscriptions s ON sa.MSISDN = s.MSISDN 
GROUP BY 
    sa.MSISDN
```

And its wrong as `s.DateRegistered` is not used in aggregate function and it is not used in group by.

How do I correct this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add s.DateRegistered to your group-by clause

Comment: Yea that works but is this the correct way to get the result ? Is there a better way?

Comment: Ok then thanks  and one more thing, this query gives result but i want to make sure this is the correct way to do `SELECT sr.ID, sr.ContentName AS service, sa.MSISDN, MIN(sa.DateRegistered) AS firstReg,  s.DateRegistered AS currentReg , MAX(sa.DateRegistered) AS previousReg FROM sms.dbo.SubscriptionsArchive sa 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DateRegistered, MSISDN, ServiceID from sms.dbo.Subscriptions) s ON sa.MSISDN = s.MSISDN 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM sms.dbo.Services) sr ON sr.Id = s.ServiceID GROUP BY sa.MSISDN, s.DateRegistered, sr.ID, sr.ContentName`

Comment: Any column that you reference in the query must be in the group-by clause unless they are inside aggregate functions

Comment: Your best bet is to run it and see

Comment: Yea it works. I just want to make sure this way is a proper way.